# HTML5 Video Embed Makes Text Darker/Lower Quality

Tags: html, video, text, background

So I'm trying to embed a 400x960px looping video as the background for a section of my site. For some reason, whenever I insert the video code all the text gets darker in color and almost lower quality. I'm using google fonts for all of my body text. The video works flawlessly, but the text changing is really confusing me.

Here's the video code:

```
<video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0"> 
<source src="videos/video1.webm" type="video/webm"> 
<source src="videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Video not supported </video>
```

Comment: This could be an antialiasing problem. The antialising has to be done in real time against the video... Have you ever seen an example of what you are trying to do render as you expect?

Comment: A similar website is http://gravitymovie.warnerbros.com/#/home. I'm trying to achieve similar results just using html. But I may just have to find a jquery substitute.